# separate logic from view with route

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express, socket.io

I'm pretty new to Node and I'm using express. 
I'm trying to implement simple file explorer.
enough talking here's some code:

(root dir is /app for this ex.)

my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var explorer = require('./routes/explorer');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/', explorer);


server.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('Server started on http://localhost:3000');
});

io.on('connection',function(client){
    console.log('connection with io established');
});

module.exports.app = app;
module.exports.server = server;
```

see that I have routing '/' to explorer

and the explorer.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('explorer',{
    currentPath : currentPath
  });
});

function getUserHome() {
      var rawPath =  process.env[(process.platform == 'win32') ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME'];
      return rawPath;
}

function clicked(){
    console.log(getUserHome());
}
```

the view explorer.ejs:

```
<div class="clickable">clickme</div>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
$('.clickable').click(function(){
    socket.emit('clicked');
});
</script>
```

basically i want to catch the "clicked" emit from the view and trigger the clicked function in the explorer.js. in other words i want the view and the explorer.js talk by socket.io, so the view can talk with the file system.
i tried few way and got bunch of error.

thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

So you've triggered the event 'clicked' on your client side :

```
// Client side :
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
$('.clickable').click(function(){
    socket.emit('clicked');
});
```

Now, you have to catch it on the server side, in the explorer.js file :

```
// Server side :
// Instanciate your socket.io on the server side
var io =  require('socket.io')(server)

// Listen for a client connection :
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    // Inside the connection, you can now declare each function for each event triggered on the client side

    socket.on('clicked', function() {
        //  This is your callback,
        //+ the code in this scope will be executed
        //+ only when the event 'clicked' is emitted
        cliked();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the comment! i want to catch it on explorer.js, and trigger the function `function clicked(){
    console.log(getUserHome());
}` that's in there.

Comment: I edited my answer, i forgot the connection event. So you have to require the 'socket.io' module and attach it to your running server. Then, you watch for the connection event (automatically fired by the client), and declare your behavior for each event inside.

Comment: thank you man but still look as it is working fine when i put the `io.sockets.on('conectnion',function(socket){...});` in app.js it works fine, but i want to separate this logic only for explorer.js, if I had say 20 routes and every route with 20 functions based on the socket data, all of them need to be hold in the app.js? I can't believe it is that centralized.

Comment: I think you can declare them over several files, you'll have declare a global variable for your `io.sockets.on( .. )` in _app.js_ and reuse it in _explorer.js_.